# Roadmap to understanding Gromov's Non-squeezing theorem

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, moduli-spaces, symplectic-topology

I'm a graduate student starting out to venture into the areas of Symplectic Geometry/Topology, and was somewhat motivated by the essence of Gromov's non-squeezing theorem which in a sense made me feel that that one of the motivations for the area of symplectic geometry is the interplay between topological and the more rigid geometric properties.

I need a roadmap to understanding the techniques involved in the proof of non-squeezing theorem better.

I've trying to make sense of this link, which sketches a proof of the theorem
 https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/pedrotti.riccardo/Riccardo_Pedrotti-Non_squeezing_theorem.pdf

I have a fairly basic idea of differential topology(from guillemin pollack  excluding intersection theory chapter), some differential geometry (regarding flows, geodesics, parallel transport). And also have a basic idea on Riemann surfaces,parts of the proof of uniformization theorem and classification of Riemann surfaces using uniformization, holomorphic forms.

I'm entirely new to the area of Moduli Spaces. 
Also I just started reading Ana Cannas Da Silva, to get some idea on how symplectic form works.
I'm hoping if someone here could suggest more references in this regard.

Also if possible, give me a better understanding or a survey of motivating results coming from symplectic geometry, and the tools that I need to internalize to get a better understanding of the proofs.

Comment: The book "Symplectic invariants and Hamiltonian dynamics" by Hofer and Zehnder gives a complete proof of nonsqueezing (amongst other things). It takes a more dynamical view than a lot of books/papers on the subject.

Comment: It's not really the easiest introduction to the subject but I learned a lot from the classic "J-Holomorphic curves and Symplectic Geometry" by McDuff and Salomon.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into this, so that I atleast have a better idea of the pre requisites required. I can eventually get to understanding the material in here.

Comment: Note that the (smaller) book "J-holomorphic curves and quantum cohomology" by McDuff-Salamon is a lighter introduction than "J-holomorphic curves and symplectic topology"; it covers much of the same material (though I don't think that nonsqueezing is there specifically) and is freely available from McDuff's website. Of course, Gromov's original paper "Pseudoholomorphic curves in symplectic manifolds" is also a great read, though somewhat sketchy and dense for a beginner!